# How to remove Google Search widget from phone completely

Tags: android, search, widget

I own a Redmi Note 7 running MIUI Global 10.3.6 (Android Version: 9 PKQ1.180904.001), unrooted. I want to remove all possibilty of using the Google Search widget on this phone (or remove the widget alltogether) and have no idea how to even approach this issue (or where to ask specifically), as it is not listed under apps or anywhere but the widget menu.

Could you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Search widget is provided by the Google App. But you can't delete it on all mobile phones without root.